# What is the common cause of short circuit in PCB design

Tags: pcb-design, clearance, creepage

In PCB design there is some clearance and creepage distances to respect according to the UL 60950 standard for example, I want to know why this distances need to be respected in PCB design, what is the risk in DC circuit if the distances is not respected.

Comment: Try googling Comparitive Tracking Index: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_Tracking_Index

Comment: Thanks it seems to be helpful i'll try to search about "electrical breakdown (tracking) properties of an insulating material."

Comment: Putting traces too close together runs the risk of creating problems during PCB fabrication.  Most PCB layout programs like Eagle, Altium, etc. will generate errors during a Design Rule Check (DRC) that will warn you of violations.

Comment: The space required between tracks, or between tracks and pads on a PC board is equivalent to the insulation required on wires in a cable, or run close together.